# Is there a way that I can scan the value of int before I implement it into the array?

Tags: c, matrix

I want here to implement the value of `array[i][j]` into itself, but firstly I have to check if it is in range between example: -99 and 99. If the input is out of these boundaries, it should stop the program.

I tried it with a do-while loop and just now I tried while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int array[2][2], i, n, j;

    /*
    do
    {
        printf("Value= ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        array[i][j] = n;
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    while(n < 99 && n > -99);
    */
    while(array[i][j] < 99 && array[i][j] > -99){

        for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
            for(j = 0; j < 2; ++j){
                printf("Value= ");
                scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    // Print the result
    for(i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < 2; ++j){
            printf("\n[%d][%d]: ", array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I got a endless loop which doesn't exit if the value is incorrect (out of these boundaries).

Comment: Check the value returned by scanf : it's the number of items scanned and stored. You are getting a zero when the user types a non-integer value and it loops forever.

Comment: array[i][j]  was accessed before assigned a value

Comment: You should learn how to code before asking questions here. `i` and `j` variables aren't initialized while you use them in a `while` loop. You check `array` entries while they are not initialized also.

Comment: If i do it like this **bold** `while(array[i][j] < 99 && array[i][j] > -99);` it continues forever. Changed scanf("%d", &array[i][j]); also

Comment: I am forging a answer, but you should learn the basics.

Comment: @TomRetterath you may check my answer if you want to use pointers and variable sized arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, tested and works:

```
int *array, i, val, n, m;

printf("Put in array size in the form of n-m where n is number of rows and m is number of columns: ");
scanf("%d-%d", &n, &m);
array = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n * m);

i = 0;
while (i < n * m) {
  printf("Value for row: %d, column: %d: ", i / m + 1, i % m + 1);
  scanf("%d", &val);
  if (val > 99 || val < -99) continue;
  *(array + i) = val;
  i++;
}

for (i = 0; i < n * m; i++) {
  if (i > 0 && i % n == 0) printf("\n");
  printf("%d\t", *(array + i));
}

free(array);
```

Without pointers (Variable sized arrays does not work on C90, needs newer standard, or you may use fixed sized arrays):

```
int i, val, n, m;

printf("Put in array size in the form of n-m where n is number of rows and m is number of columns: ");
scanf("%d-%d", &n, &m);
int array[n][m];

i = 0;
while (i < n * m) {
  printf("Value for row: %d, column: %d: ", i / m + 1, i % m + 1);
  scanf("%d", &val);
  if (val > 99 || val < -99) continue;
  array[i / m][i % m] = val;
  i++;
}

for (i = 0; i < n * m; i++) {
  if (i > 0 && i % n == 0) printf("\n");
  printf("%d\t", array[i / m][i % m]);
}
```

Comment: [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive] at line 36.
array = malloc(sizeof(int) * n * m);

Comment: @TomRetterath I always forgot this type thing on malloc. But interestingly, it works on online GDB compiler. Fixed it now.

Comment: @TomRetterath compile with C compiler, not C++

Comment: im compiling it with C. Fact is that the value gets stored even when it is out of the boudraries. Ideas? (I tried your program with input 2-2, 99, 999, 9999, -9999)

Comment: @TomRetterath yeah, i fixed it know. I changed the wrong and to or in the first edit. Now everything fixed.

Comment: @TomRetterath By the way it includes 99 and -99. If they are out of boundaries change with `>=  99` and `<= 99`.

Comment: Can you do this without any pointers since they are new to me?

Comment: @TomRetterath I did it, note that I also fixed some bug. It was not visible because we tried with a square array. But `/n` and `%n` should use `m` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your array undefeated values, in the first while you try to check random number in your memory. And so your i j will be random number. 
Put if statement in your for loop to check the value in array, and delete while loop